# Implementing a semaphore in ARM using SWP

Tags: arm, semaphore

In [this webiste](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/arm-embedded/implementing-semaphores-on-arm-processors/#:%7E:text=The%20SWP%20instruction%20can%20be,by%20a%20write%20to%20memory.), the following code is given for implementing a semaphore in ARM.

```
LOCKED EQU 0         ; define value indicating

 LDR   r1, <addr>    ; load semaphore address
 LDR   r0, =LOCKED   ; preload "locked" value

spin_lock
 SWP   r0, r0, [r1]  ; swap register value with semaphore
 CMP   r0, #LOCKED   ; if semaphore was locked already
 BEQ   spin_lock     ;     retry
```

Why is SWP used here? Why is the comparison not done with register r1 itself? Has it got to do something with the fact that SWP is an atomic instruction?

Comment: Yes, in this case SWP atomically does something like `temp = [r1]; [r1] = r0; r0 = temp;`. However this instruction is deprecated in ARMv6+, so if you don't want to disable interrupts, you will want to use `LDREX`/`STREX` instead.

Comment: Thank you, @Groo. But I didn't quite understand the purpose of SWP. What if I load the semaphore in [r1] to register r0 and compare r0 with "locked" value? What is the purpose of swapping?

Comment: because if two threads do the same thing (just set [r1] to a value), you don't know if it was your thread that did this.

Comment: @user7080: The load and compare will tell you whether the lock is already locked.  It will not actually lock the semaphore; for that you have to do a store.  And the store can't be separate from the load, or else you have a race condition.  So you have to do them atomically, and that's what `SWP` does.

Comment: ldrex/strex does not replace swp btw.  they did depricate it nevertheless.   using a test and set or swap is not uncommon for this kind of thing.   they use swp as shown in the code it is atomic so your read and write cannot be interfered with another process so if you read a non lock and write a lock then it was unlocked and now you have the lock

Comment: r1 is just the address the address by itself wont do anything for you you have to have (prefer to have) a hardware/silicon mechanism that lets you test and set in an atomic way.  swp does/did this but certainly it can tie up the bus(es).